# ARDUINO Buzzer playing sound when it shouldn't

Tags: arduino-uno

So I made this kind of a temperature/humidity sensor and decided to add a fire sensor feature. So it all works fine, right? No, I also decided I want a buzzer to that. Tested it, works well, so I thrown it into my project.
Started it up [project], lit up a lighter, works fine, LEDs blink, a text is shown, buzzer plays an alarm. But then, after the fire was out, the buzzer continued to play one of two tones, even though there was no fire. Here's the code, to make it all clear:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <dht.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);
dht DHT;

#define FLAME 13
#define DHT11_PIN 8
#define ALARM A5
const int a9 = 9, a10 = 10, a11 = 11, a12 = 12;

byte z[8] = {
  B00100,
  B00000,
  B11111,
  B00001,
  B00010,
  B00100,
  B11111,
  B00000,
};

byte st[8] = {
  0b00110,
  0b01001,
  0b01001,
  0b00110,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
};

void setup(){
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.createChar(0, st);
  lcd.createChar(1, z);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode((a9, a10, a11, a12), OUTPUT);
  pinMode(FLAME, INPUT);
  pinMode(ALARM, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // Flame sensor code for Robojax.com

  int fire = digitalRead(FLAME);// read FLAME sensor

  if(fire == HIGH)
  {
    analogWrite(a9, 255);
    analogWrite(a10, 255);
    lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
    lcd.print("Po");
    lcd.print(char(1));
    lcd.print("ar!");
    tone(ALARM, 4300);
    delay(150);
    analogWrite(a9, 0);
    analogWrite(a10, 0);
    lcd.clear();
    tone(ALARM, 3500);
    delay(150);
  } else {
    lcd.createChar(0, st);
    int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
    lcd.home();
    lcd.print("Temp.: ");
    lcd.print(DHT.temperature);
    if(DHT.temperature >= 20.00 && DHT.temperature < 25) {
      analogWrite(a11, 255);
      delay(750);
      analogWrite(a11, 0);  
      delay(750);
    } else if(DHT.temperature >= 25 && DHT.temperature < 30) {
      analogWrite(a10, 255);
      delay(250);
      analogWrite(a10, 0);
      delay(250);
    } else if(DHT.temperature >= 30) {
      analogWrite(a9, 255);
    }
    lcd.print(char(0));
    lcd.print("C");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Wilg.: ");
    lcd.print(DHT.humidity);
    if(DHT.humidity >= 45.00 && DHT.humidity < 60.00) {
      digitalWrite(a12, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(a12, LOW);
      delay(250);
    } else if(DHT.humidity >= 60.00) {
      digitalWrite(a12, HIGH);
    }
    lcd.print(" %");
    delay(750);

  }



  delay(200);
}
```

So, what I mean is that even though *fire* is changed from **HIGH** to **LOW** and other part of the code is executed, the buzzer continues to play.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: StackOverflow is a terrible debugger, and it sounds like you need to debug into this. You can even print debug values to the serial port. I'd look carefully at how things like `tone` work within the loop. I bet you have to reset it at the beginning of the loop. In some cases you want to reset or initialize state to some known value before fetching your current values.

Comment: Can you explain how can I do either of two options you described?

Comment: I've gone ahead and answered this one, even though it could have used a bit more research on the part of the OP. Not to mention that this probably really belongs on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ (Or at least the OP should be redirected to Arduino.SE for research purposes if this does not meet the basic requirements for a Question there.)

Comment: For example: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?q=tone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [documentation for `tone`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/):

> A duration can be specified, otherwise the wave continues until a call
>   to `noTone()`.

So, you probably need to reset your tone on every loop beginning before checking the values of the sensors (or explicitly invoke `notone` on the LOW branch), or use the 3-arg version of `tone`.

I have no idea how `tone` and `delay` might interact, though.

I'd probably make the actual tone sounding routine its own task. The idea is that you would start the alarm task and then reset it when appropriate. But for now make sure your state is reset at the beginning of every loop, or each branch resets anything it has to explicitly, if tasks sound too advanced.

Make sure you learn the basic "print" debugging in the Arduino world. Simple [write logging to the serial port](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write) where it can be read on the IDE is invaluable.

Finally: use functions! If you put everything in `loop` your programs will get unreadable as they grow. For example, if you have some state you want to reset every time (e.g., running tasks like tones, values, flags) then create an `init()` function that `loop` calls first so any given loop has good starting state.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I basically added the `noTone(ALARM);` when no fire is detected. Turned out it works now, although I have a strong feeling I tried it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Limitations of the Piezo Buzzer

Here are some things to consider when using the piezo buzzer:

- You can’t use tone() while also using analogWrite() on pins 3 or 11